# "socialize" with activities after it

Tags: grammar, word-usage

So, from my experience, "socialize" is often used to imply any activities that include interacting socially with someone, and the phrase itself does not have any specific activities attached. We just use it like "socialize [adv] with someone". No activities in the middle.

However, [a lot of Vietnamese site have this example](https://khoahoc.vietjack.com/question/688581/she-is-a-kind-of-woman-who-does-not-care-much-of-work-but-generally-meals) that goes somewhat like

> She is a kind of woman who does not care much of work but generally *socialises* meals, movies or late nights at a club with her colleagues.

This just sounds off and weird to me, but they insist that this is correct. Is this true?

Comment: I searched for your phrase but just got the ice-fishing monster (no results) So could you please link to some of these Vietnamese sites, please.

Comment: You can try googling "She is a kind of woman who does not care much of work but generally". One example site is https://khoahoc.vietjack.com/question/688581/she-is-a-kind-of-woman-who-does-not-care-much-of-work-but-generally-meals

Comment: Thanks,  I was searching for the whole phrase, but it was a gapped question.  I've added it to the question.

Comment: I've also changed it to use the actual phrase on the site.  It doesn't make much difference in this case, but sometimes if you change the quote you can introduce other mistakes or make the answer not applicable to the actual problem.

Comment: It should be **attends**, not socialises.   Also there are two errors.  It's should be  "**the** kind of woman", and "doesn't care much **for** work".

Comment: Or "doesn't care much *about* work" too. Have no idea how this abomination of a sentence even pass the QC and make it to 90% of Vietnamese English site. Just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: your example is not idiomatic, at least not idiomatic in American English.

I suspect that the problem lies in the relatively arbitrary nature of English prepositions. What is meant is

> I socialize **at** meals and movies with my friends

although even that strikes me as at least awkward.

To my mind, the actual verb in that sentence is “socialize with,” a **prepositional verb**, and “my friends” is the direct object of the verb. The most natural formulation is

> I socialize with my friends at meals and movies

Comment: "my friends" is not a direct object. Prepositional verbs are verbs that can be complemented by prepositional phrases. The preposition isn't part of the verb to the extent that the object is a direct object. It's still the object of a preposition, so indirect.

Answer (score 3):

*Socialize* in this sense is an intransitive verb. You socialize *with* other people, you don't socialize something. Your Vietnamese friends are using the word incorrectly.

Comment: There is a specialised meaning, as in "We send our young boy to play school in order to **socialise** him". In other words, to teach him to interact with other children, sharing, playing "nicely" etc.

Comment: @PeterJennings - Yes, that's why I said _in this sense_.

Answer (score 1):

The usage you have seen is incorrect. Socialise (or socialize) used to mean 'to meet and spend time with people in a friendly way' is an **intransitive** verb (that is, a verb that is not used with an object) It can be followed by prepositions such as 'with', 'at' etc, and words describing how a person socialises - e.g. I socialise with my friends at parties, my child socialises at school, and so on. We can also say we socialise a lot, or not much, or that we don't, or rarely, socialize.

> socialize verb
>
> (British English also socialise)
>
> ​[intransitive] socialize (with somebody)
>
> to meet and spend time with people in a friendly way, in order to
> enjoy yourself
>
> SYNONYM mix
>
> *I enjoy socializing with the other students.*
>
> *Maybe you should socialize more.*

[Socialize (Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/socialize)